# Pandas dataframe can't save milliseconds to csv

Tags: python, pandas

I use this code to export data from cassandra to csv:

```
import pandas as pd
from cassandra import ConsistencyLevel
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from cassandra.auth import PlainTextAuthProvider
from cassandra.query import SimpleStatement


def getClockInDataFromCassandra(para_ip,para_username,para_password,para_save_path,para_begin_time,para_end_time):
    try:
        contact_points = [para_ip]
        auth_provider = PlainTextAuthProvider(username=para_username, password=para_password)
        cluster = Cluster(contact_points=contact_points, auth_provider=auth_provider)
        session = cluster.connect()
        cql_str = 'select * from mytest.table1 ;' 
        simple_statement = SimpleStatement(cql_str, consistency_level=ConsistencyLevel.ONE,fetch_size=None)
        execute_result = session.execute(simple_statement, timeout=None)
        result = execute_result._current_rows
        cluster.shutdown()
        df = pd.DataFrame(result)
        df['clock_time_add_8hour'] = df['clock_time'] + pd.Timedelta(hours=8)
        df_result = df[(df['clock_time_add_8hour'] > para_begin_time) & (df['clock_time_add_8hour'] <= para_end_time)]
        df_result = df_result.drop(['clock_time_add_8hour'], axis=1)
        df_result.to_csv(para_save_path, index=False, mode='w', header=True)
    except Exception as ex:
        raise ex


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ip= 'XX.XX.XX.XX'
    username = 'XXX'
    password = 'XXX'
    csvPath = r'./20201229.csv'
    beginTime='2020-12-01 12:00:00'
    endTime='2020-12-01 15:00:00'
    getClockInDataFromCassandra(ip,username,password,csvPath,beginTime,endTime)
```

But when I open the csv, I find that there are no milliseconds in the date, like this:

```
clock_time
2020/12/1 4:30:13
2020/12/1 4:25:14
2020/12/1 5:01:59
```

Actually there are milliseconds in the dataframe, like this:
[image]

How can I save milliseconds into csv,I want `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f`?

Comment: Have you checked the contents of your csv using a text editor or were you checking using Excel or something similar?

Comment: When I open the save file with microsoft office,the displayed data has no milliseconds,But when I use notepad++ to open the csv, I can see milliseconds, I think this is indeed a problem with the compiler.

Comment: What compiler? It's a display problem. You need to learn how to adjust the display of datetime values in Excel.